# mirror zend framework (1) from svn to git with git svn and multiple trunks

Tags: git, svn, zend-framework, mirror

What I want is a git repo with zend and zendx as mirror. After a few hours I still didn't get it to work.

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/extras/trunk/

Among other methods I tried this one too:

```
>git svn clone -r HEAD http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk zend
>cd zend

.git/config
[svn-remote "zend"]
    url = http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/svn/zend
[svn-remote "zendx"]
    url = http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/extras/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/svn/zendx

>git svn fetch zendx -r HEAD
```

if you have a look at the library folder only Zend is in there and not ZendX

even after git svn rebase zendx

also tried:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework
    fetch = standard/trunk:refs/remotes/zend
    fetch = extras/trunk:refs/remotes/zendx
```

It must have something to do with cache, refs, or someting I don't know

I've read the following pages (among others)

```
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-git-svn-manage-standard-and-non-standard-branches

http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git

http://yoush.homelinux.org:8079/tech/git-svn-usage-tips

http://ominian.com/2010/03/02/bridging-the-gap-git-svn-b-f-f/

http://www.codeography.com/2010/03/17/howto-mirror-git-to-subversion.html

http://code.google.com/p/remote-testbed/wiki/SvnSynchronization
```

I know there are mirrors:

```
http://gitorious.org/zf

https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror
```

But I need one myself due to security and work related.

If you have a look at all the pages I read, they all have a different method but the basics are the same. One svn mirror is not that hard but two from the same repo is difficult (to me).

Does anyone know what to do so I can reproduce?

(I only clone/fetch/rebase the HEAD else all commits are downloaded witch takes a while)

One extra side question, I know they are working on version Zend 2.0 (with git.zendframework.com), does anyone know when this will be production ready?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be none-standard svn structure in zf project. Matthew O'Phinney may have spotted an answer, take a look on http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/222-Cloning-the-ZF-SVN-repository-in-Git.html